Teamcenter AWS Displaying an image on a style sheet
I want to display a picture attached to an object (for example, via the TC_Attaches connection). It is necessary that one picture is displayed, linked to a specific connection. How can this be done? The style sheet configuration in my case occurs through htmlpanel
I tried using:
Awp0GalleryViewer - it displays all attached objects (including text files, PDF and so on), which does not suit me;
Awp0ImageViewer - for some reason it doesn't display anything
 - I don't know what to put in "source" to display the image
